# QProgressDialog: How to adjust the size of the dialog to fit its contents?

Tags: c++, qt, qprogressbar

I test with code below:

```
QProgressDialog* dialog = new QProgressDialog("Message", "Close", 0, 10);
dialog->setWindowTitle("Long Long Long Long Title");
dialog->setCancelButtonText("Long Long Long Click this button to cancel");
dialog->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
dialog->adjustSize();
dialog->setValue(5);
```

The title and the cancel button text are cut. I called adjustSize(), but it didn't work. How to adjust the size of the dialog to fit its contents?

[image]

Comment: Use `Layout`s, check [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-layouts.html).

Comment: It doesn't look pretty when a button has such a long name. You better to set a short name and use long description as a tool tip text.

Comment: @KernelPanic, The QProgressDialog is provide by QT, Can I edit its layout?

Comment: @vahancho, Yes, but I need a long text for some reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following: use the QLayout...

```
QProgressDialog* dialog = new QProgressDialog("Message", "Close", 0, 10);
dialog->setWindowTitle("Long Long Long Long Title");
dialog->setCancelButtonText("Long Long Long Click this button to cancel");
dialog->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
dialog->setValue(5);

QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
foreach (QObject *obj, dialog->children()) {
    QWidget *widget = qobject_cast<QWidget *>(obj);
    if (widget)
        layout->addWidget(widget);
}
dialog->setLayout(layout);
```